# Modeled car disappears in 'play mode' of game engine

Tags: modeling, game-engine

I spent some time modeling a taxi, but when I press <kbd>P</kbd> to go into play mode of the Blender Game Engine everything gets messed up. I have included screenshots below:

[image: Blender]

[image: Play mode]

BLENDER GAME FILE: [Blender file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B__Lv_qP_yf7TE9OQTVsWmpteE0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your normals are facing the wrong direction. The game engine does not render faces which are facing away from the camera since these are behind the object. However, your normals are facing the wrong way which causes the exact opposite to happen - back faces are drawn, front faces are not.

- Select the problematic object and switch to edit mode with **Tab**.
- Press **A** to select everything.
- Press **W**-**R** to remove any duplicate vertices (as they may break the next step).
- Press **Ctrl-N** to make normals consistent.